# What is the difference between for...in loop and jQuery each() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I am using the following scripts to iterate the object (I don't know which one is best to use, please tell me which one is the best):

```
var days = {Sunday: 0, Monday: 1, Tuesday: 2, Wednesday: 3, Thursday: 4, Friday: 5, Saturday: 6};

$.each(days, function(key, value){
    $('#days').append('<li>' + key + '(' + value + ')</li>');
});


for(var key in days){
    $('#days').append('<li>' + key + '(' + days[key] + ')</li>');
}
```

Comment: Without comparison criterias it's not possible to compare (and choose the best). Which is the best: an orange or an apple?

Comment: Define *best* for this question.

Comment: @alex: don't worry, I'm already here ;-P

Comment: I think in this particular case (array with 7 elements) it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Note: you don't have an array there, you have an object.

Answer (score 4):

Either way, you should be caching that selector:

```
var elem = $( '#days' );
$.each(days,function(key,value){
    elem.append('<li>'+key+'('+value+')</li>');
});
```

.each() would be better in this case. The pattern is cleaner.

With a for loop, you'd want to use obj.hasOwnProperty(key) so that you don't dredge through inherited properties... Which adds another layer of indenting:

```
var elem = $( '#days' );
for( var key in days ){
  if( days.hasOwnProperty( key ) ){
    elem.append('<li>'+key+'('+days[key]+')</li>');
  }
}
```

Comment: Regarding use of `.hasOwnProperty()`, in the case(s) where it is necessary you'd need it for `$.each()` too.

Answer (score 2):

It is clear without any performance tests that native javascript for loop is faster, but there is no big difference for small arrays like 10-20 small items. So use whichever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Features of `$.each`: It will stop looping if the function returns `false`. It works for both objects and arrays. `$(this)` refers to the current element being processed.

Drawbacks of `$.each`: There's a little more overhead, as it does some initial checking of arguments and has to perform a function call for each element.

But as others said, the overhead is likely to be negligible unless you're processing a large number of items.

One other benefit of `$.each()` is simply the easy recognition of the word -- having it at the beginning of a statement makes it obvious that you're looping over a collection. It's also easy to search for.

Comment: _"It will stop looping if the function returns_ `false`" - Note that this doesn't make it better than a `for` loop, given that `for` loops have an equivalent feature (the `break` statement).

Comment: It's just a matter of one doing it automatically for you, while the other requires an explicit check. $.each() is just a convenience function, this is just one more convenience.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "doing it automatically" in the sense of exiting the loop early. `return false` does it from `$.each()`, but `break` does it from `for`. What is the explicit check you mention?

Comment: Compare: `$.each(array, somefunc);` with `for (var key in array) {if(!somefunc(array[key])) break}`. There's not much difference if you're using an immediate anonymous function, but if you're calling a named function that already returns `false`, it saves an extra check.

Comment: OK, now I understand what you mean, thanks. You're talking about the case where a `for..in` calls a function to do all the work on each iteration like `$.each()` does. I was talking about the case where the work is done directly in the `for..in` loop block (as shown in the question, and a very common usage).